# Triggering a Post Request with a change of a Slider's value in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, slider

I'm new to Javascript and JQuery and was wondering if there was some sort of event to trigger a Post Request whenever the value of a slider changes. The closest thing I've found was having the Post Request trigger when ever I click or unclick the slider, but I want an event that will dynamically trigger the Post Request as I slide the slider.

For example, the user can manually move the slider or use buttons to increment/decrements it. I would like to trigger the Post request whenever the value of the slider is altered, so it covers both potential input cases.

This is my code thus far and it triggers as intended:

```
 $(function(){
      $("#frame-slider").on('input click', function() {

      ...

          $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',

                ...

                success: function(response) {
                    console.log(response);

                },

                error: function(error) {
                     console.log(error);
                }
          });
     });
});
```

Comment: There are many types of slider each has different functionality. Based on which slider you want the solution?

Comment: The range slider? I think that's the name of the type of the slider I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-change

```
$( ".selector" ).slider({
  change: function( event, ui ) {}
});
```

where `.selector` is the css selector to your slider element (maybe you gave it an `id="myselector"` -- the css would selector would be `"#myselector"`

Comment: I tried this multiple times and it unfortunately didn't work. I have edited the original post to include my code this far.

Comment: can you post a jsbin - the ajax post bit is not relevant to your question so lets leave that out for now.